# GNU make with VPATH: target which appears circular, but really shouldn't be

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, circular-dependency

I have a rule in my `Makefile` which is intended to create a symlink to a file in a different directory:

```
VPATH = ../source
foo: foo
    ln -s $< $@
```

Even though I intend for the target to resolve to `./foo` and the dependency to resolve to `../source/foo`, I understand why `make` sees it as circular. Is there a way to express this rule in a way that is not circular?

Comment: why not remove `foo` as a dependency and change `$<` to `../source/foo`? I guess you could also change the dependency from `foo` to `../source/foo` and get rid of the `VPATH` vairable.

Comment: Changing the dependency to `../source/foo` and getting rid of `VPATH` seems to work, although that means I have to modify anything else in the `Makefile` that depends on `VPATH`. I was hoping to avoid that, but it's not too much work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the link does not depend on the changes of the link target; it only needs to exist.  Therefore, there is no ordinary prerequisite needed at all, and the simplest fragment to do what you want would be

```
foo:
    ln -sf ../source/$@
```

However, this won't work correctly if you still need your `VPATH` for other purposes.  If that is so, then it seems to me the simplest way would be to ignore `VPATH` for this rule by using absolute path:

```
VPATH := ../source
$(CURDIR)/foo:
    ln -sf ../source/$(@F)
```

Finally, if the file `../source/foo` is also a target which is generated by Make, then maybe the best way would be:

```
VPATH := ../source

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(CURDIR)/foo: | ../source/$$(@F)
    ln -sf $|
```

Note that we are not depending on the changes of the prerequisite here, only on the existence of it.

By the way, the reason why I am using `-f` option is because, Make should support `-B` option.  That option will not work unless you use `-f` here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying here falls under the category of "VPATH abuse".

My experience is repeatedly pointing me toward the mantra "explicit is better than implicit" and this is one of the reasons why. Contrary to the assertions in the GNU make Manual, my experience has led me to believe that in larger, more complex projects, you need to be *more* explicity, not less, because the size makes it more difficult to locate files, unless their path is explicit.

I also believe that a lot of the need to use VPATH stems from the use of recursive make, where you're not building complete dependency trees; write your build system properly and you just don't need VPATH at all.

On a related subject, I'm a firm believer in only specifying one or two `-I` directories: your top-level `src/` and `include/` directories and make *all* inclussions relative to these paths. Again, on larger, more complex projects, seing `#include "my/really/cool/thing.h"` is soooo much informative than simply `#include "thing.h"`.

That said, I am open to the idea of using VPATH for libraries, especially system libraries, because you can use the `-lfoo` syntax, but I wouldn't want to use it as a general rule, because it could threaten build reproducibility.